# What is the "Mode" parameter in duplicate (edit mode) window?

Tags: edit-mode

I can't find out, what does it do, never noticed it before.
[image]

Comment: Well, it exists for quite a long time now, but I never found any information on what it does or if it's non-functional (nowadays, but maybe wasn't in the past?). Never found a site where it says something about its purpose. The Blender documentation only mentions that the setting exists in the toolbar, with no hint on what it could be used for... [Blender manual: Duplicate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/duplicate.html)

Comment: It's quite stupid that the developers leave a functionless numeric field in the UI...

Comment: Yeah, must be really "stupid" people who develop something like Blender  Maybe we are just stupid because we don't know what it is. This is no developers' site, perhaps ask one of them and they know more about it?

Comment: This is a quite authoritarian answer. Blender is doubtless a very good program in many respect, and I didn't say, that the developers are stupid, but there are a lot of stupid problems in the design, and a lot of these would be trivial to fix. 

For example why they can't implement a polygon lasso tool? Every single 3D and 2D software has it. Why drag-n-drop doesn't work imported 3D file formats? Why images are not shown in usable size in image selection windows? And so on...

Comment: @Denatural switch software if you don't like it. it's as easy as that. it is free anyway, can't complain for something that is free :)

Comment: @Denatural And apart from that, this is no discussion forum and no developers' site, so it's not about philosophising why some things aren't implemented, we are trying to find solutions with what we have. To complain about missing features you have to talk to the developers. And if they leave "stupid problems in the design" that are "trivial to fix", then first of all it sounds like the people who aren't fixing it must be stupid, and secondly everybody can become a developer for Blender. Why don't you try it fixing it?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie
I don't want to switch. I just can't understand, why some very basic and standard feature is missing from a software, that is one of the most (is not the most) widespread 3D modeler/renderer on the world.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann
I shared some of my feature-requests on rightclickselect forum, but none of them was implemented. My C++ skills are not yet enough for constructive modifying Blender core source. I downloaded it and compiled, but quite hard to understand te codebase. But for a coder who is familiar in it, these fixes and features are not too complicated.

Comment: @Denatural Okay, none of them were implemented, but I assure you complaining on this site won't get them implemented either because, again, this is no developers' site.